# Getting multiple CORS errors while using POST API

Tags: node.js, post, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am getting multiple CORS error while trying to upload an image through a POST request. I have created a POST API on AWS API Gateway which triggers a lambda function written in Node js. The API works fine with Postman as it allows CORS but it is giving multiple errors on different browsers.

Errors are as below:-

- On Firefox

[image]

- On Chrome
  [image]

**Below are the request headers:-**

```
Method request headers: {
        sec - fetch - mode = cors,
        sec - fetch - site = cross - site,
        accept - language = en - US,
        en;q = 0.9,
        hi;q = 0.8,
        access - control - allow - headers = Origin,
        X - Requested - With,
        Content - Type,
        Accept,
        Authorization,
        origin = null,
        User - Agent = Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 76.0 .3809 .100 Safari / 537.36,
        X - Forwarded - Proto = https,
        Host = xxxxxxx.execute - api.us - east - 2. amazonaws.com,
        X - Forwarded - Port = 443,
        X - Amzn - Trace - Id = Root = 1 - 5 d5fd816 - 4 c1ac880ed09a50047ecda00,
        accept = * /*, access-control-allow-origin=*, X-Forwarded-For=103.97.240.210, content-type=application/json, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br}
```

**Request headers on Chrome**
[image]

**Below are the **response headers**:-**

```
Endpoint response headers: {
    Date = Fri,
    23 Aug 2019 12: 12: 07 GMT,
    Content - Type = application / json,
    Content - Length = 1077,
    Connection = keep - alive,
    x - amzn - RequestId = 46 a264c2 - 44 d7 - 4026 - 9168 - f227e758f078,
    X - Amz - Function - Error = Unhandled,
    x - amzn - Remapped - Content - Length = 0,
    X - Amz - Executed - Version = $LATEST,
    X - Amzn - Trace - Id = root = 1 - 5 d5fd816 - 4 c1ac880ed09a50047ecda00;sampled = 0
}
```

**Response headers on postman**
[image]

**Below is my code**
Clientside: index.html

```
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="application/json">

    Enter the Employee Id: <input type="text" name="empId"><br>
    Upload the Employee Photo: </h2><input type="file" name="PhotoName"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="PhotoContent" value="Upload Photo"><br><br>
</form>
</div>

 <script src="upload.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Clientside: upload.js**

```
const url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/upload';
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;


    const reader = new FileReader() 
    reader.onload = handleFileLoad;
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];
        console.log(file);

    }

});

function handleFileLoad(event){ 
    console.log(event);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', event.target.result);
    console.log('final file ', formData.get('data'));

    let data = {
        "fileName" : 'tmp123',
        "user_avatar" : event.target.result
    };

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers : {
            'Origin' : 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/upload',
            'content-type' : 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
        },
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Serverside(lambda): index.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { parse } = require('querystring');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {   
    if (event.method === 'POST') {
    let body = '';
    event.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log(
            parse(body)
        );
        res.end('ok');
    });
}
    //  var event = '{ "user_avatar": "asas" }' ;

    let encodedImage = JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar;
    let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
    //  var filePath = "avatars/" + event.queryStringParameters.username + ".jpg"
     var filePath = JSON.parse(event.body).file_name

     var params = {
       "Body": decodedImage,
       "Bucket": "test-bkt-rahul",
       "Key": filePath  
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
       if(err) {
           callback(err, null);
       } else {
           let response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ""
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(data),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
           callback(null, response);
    }
    });

};
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CORS headers are supposed to be set on server side. Try adding both `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'` to your server's response.

Comment: Hi @Teh I am still getting the same error, even after adding above headers to server side Node js code.

Comment: @Teh One more doubt I am having is that, if I have already enabled CORS headers on OPTIONS method, Do I also have to add same headers for POST method which is under the same resource? Because currently, I have enabled CORS on OPTIONS method and also sending same headers from Node Js code of POST method. Can it create conflict in headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the issue is resolved.

- I was getting a 403 response code because I was using the incorrect endpoint.
- I was getting CORS error because exception handling was not done on my server-side code. On exception, the code was not sending CORS headers in the response.

Answer (score 3):

Setting Access-Control-Allow-Oriigin to null will disallow all origins. Set it to `*` instead.

```
"headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
```

Comment: I have already added the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" header on both server-side and client-side code. I am still getting the same CORS error.

Comment: Your posted code says otherwise, but ok. No need for it on the client, it's a response header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an OPTIONS method for your resource, with a MOCK response that sends those headers back, and allow these headers on API Gateway as well. If you select your resource on api gateway and click the top drop down, click enable cors, it will set that resource/method up for you, and take you through an intuitive work flow, to allow these and pass their values back and forth between client and your back end(lambda in this case).

You can also specify METHODS to allow, '*' or subset('GET,POST')

Try these:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
```

**AWS API Gateway CORS Docs**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have enabled CORS while creating the API and OPTIONS method was also created at that time. I have tried updating the OPTIONS method headers as per your suggestion but it is still giving the same errors. But when I make API call from the browser, I only see the POST method and not the OPTIONS method. Is it fine?

Comment: I am also seeing 403 response code on POST request with response - {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} on Firefox and no response on Chrome. I don't think it is a Authentication issue as I can access the API from postman without token.

Comment: One more doubt I am having is that, if I have already enabled CORS headers on OPTIONS method, Do I also have to add same headers for POST method which is under same resource. Because currently, I have enabled CORS on OPTIONS method and also sending headers from Node Js code of POST method.

Comment: Strange. Could you please post the request method config for the options and for the post method? I would try to enable CloudWatch access logs as well on the stage, subsequently try to hit the API endpoint a few times from browser and from postman, and post those.

Comment: I have enabled CloudWatch logs. The issue is resolved. Previously, I was getting a 403 response code because I was using the incorrect endpoint. Even after correcting it I was getting CORS error because exception handling was not done on my server-side code. On error, it was not sending CORS headers. Thanks for your help.